# How to solve error 13 when connect remotely from SQL Server to shared path using python?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sql-server-2019, python-3.10

I working with SQL Server 2019; I face issue I can't read data from Excel file using python from SQL Server.

Python used is version 3.10

What I try is:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
        @language = N'Python',
        @script = N'import pandas as pd
                    df = pd.read_excel(r"\\192.168.7.9\Import\10\test\testData.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
                    print(df)';
```

I get this error:

> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 48
> An external script error occurred:
>
> self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self.io)
> File "D:\SQL Data\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\xlrd_init.py", line 111, in open_workbook
> with open(filename, "rb") as f:
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\192.168.7.9\Import\10\test\testData.xlsx'
>
> SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution. Check the output for more information.
>
> STDOUT message(s) from external script:
> SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\SQL Data\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 605, in rx_sql_satellite_call
> rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
>
> File "D:\SQL Data\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 375, in rx_native_call

I check remote path I can exporter it and write to it and read.

I check Excel file it not open.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64047240/execute-r-script-with-sp-execute-external-script-in-mssql/64059623#64059623

Comment: thank you for reply what meaning  assigning full access rights to the folder and script file to user 'MSSQLLaunchpad'